# Android Kotlin Access to Files in Download Directory API > 29

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, file-access

I´m trying to get access to Files in the Device Download/ Directory.
Since the Scoped Storage updates and Restrictions for the ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE Intent couldnt i find any way to get a URI or smth to work with.
I Want to read all Files in the Download Directory to see if they fit my searched MIME-Type.

I tried:

- `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)` -> Depricated
- `context.contentResolver.query(MediaStore.Downloads.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_INTERNAL),projection,null,null,null)` -> U cant access Files that are not created by ur App in the Download Dir (https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media)
- Getting Access With the ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE Intent -> Since API 30 dosnt show Download Directory anymore (https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#grant-access-directory)

If u need more information let me know.
I hope someone has an Idea :)

Comment: `Restrictions for the ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE Intent `  The user can indeed not select the Download directory. But with ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT every file in it.

Comment: If you want to list all files in the `Download` directory in the classic way you need to ask for `all files access` starting with `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission.

Comment: `Since API 30 dosnt show Download Directory anymore`Well hard to believe. Not here. All is shown but the directory is not selectable.

Comment: `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` is the only option:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CGD1Kr7A77Y&t=4s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the help!
The solution was to use the MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions.
Now I can access all files to scan for the wanted file types.

Comment: Note: this will help only if you don't want to publish to Play Store, otherwise you will need to use `Storage Access Framework`